# fibers@1.0.15 install node_modules/fibers node build.js || nodejs build.js

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install, node-modules, node-fibers

I'm have error when trying to run sudo npm install in node 10, in local server its work perfect.

error:
    fibers@1.0.15 install /home/tickets/www/tickets_parser/node_modules/fibers
    node build.js || nodejs build.js

```
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/home/tickets/www/tickets_parser/node_modules/fibers/build'
gyp ERR! System Linux 4.4.0-97-generic
gyp ERR! command "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--release"
gyp ERR! cwd /home/tickets/www/tickets_parser/node_modules/fibers
gyp ERR! node -v v10.0.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.6.2
gyp ERR! not ok
node-gyp exited with code: 1
Please make sure you are using a supported platform and node version. If you
would like to compile fibers on this machine please make sure you have setup your
build environment--
Windows + OS X instructions here: https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp
Ubuntu users please run: sudo apt-get install g++ build-essential
Alpine users please run: sudo apk add python make g++
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/home/tickets/www/tickets_parser/node_modules/fibers/build'
gyp ERR! System Linux 4.4.0-97-generic
gyp ERR! command "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--release"
gyp ERR! cwd /home/tickets/www/tickets_parser/node_modules/fibers
gyp ERR! node -v v10.0.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.6.2
gyp ERR! not ok
node-gyp exited with code: 1
Please make sure you are using a supported platform and node version. If you
would like to compile fibers on this machine please make sure you have setup your
build environment--
Windows + OS X instructions here: https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp
Ubuntu users please run: sudo apt-get install g++ build-essential
Alpine users please run: sudo apk add python make g++
npm WARN tickets_parser@0.0.0 No description
npm WARN tickets_parser@0.0.0 No repository field.
npm WARN tickets_parser@0.0.0 No license field.

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! fibers@1.0.15 install: node build.js || nodejs build.js
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the fibers@1.0.15 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR! /home/tickets/.npm/_logs/2018-05-14T19_08_18_241Z-debug.log

thanks
```

Comment: On which OS(Mac, windows, Ubuntu, RHEL..) you are trying to install node fiber?

Comment: Hi, ubuntu 16.04, thanks

Comment: Have you tried with latest fibers `2.0.2`?